# MongoDB Encoding Error

Tags: mongodb

Before I import my file I use iconv `-f ISO-8859-1 -t utf-8 -c` and all the texts looks fine. Then after I import the file and pull up the collection all the text in my db has the symbols again. Is there anything I can do to fix this or does MongoDb just not accept latin Characters?

Step1:  `iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf-8 -c airports.csv`

Output: Peña,

Step2:    `mongoimport -d test -c airports --type csv --file airports.csv --headerline`

Output: Pe�a,

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to contain a specific example that isn't working?

Comment: @JohnnyHK when I do the encoding everything comes out fine. When I do the import it changes all the letters to symbols. I don't know if I'm skipping a step and not importing the encoded version or if I'm doing something else wrong.

Comment: I meant a specific example of the CSV you're importing that reproduces the problem.

Comment: The CSV is just a list of airports. The names that are in Spanish aren't being encoded correctly, like the one in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1:  `iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf-8 airports.csv > airportsencoded.csv`

Step2:  `mongoimport -d test -c airports --type csv --file airportsencoded.csv --headerline`

this solved it.